# Date picker does not open first click on textfield in swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have `datePicker` view that does not open at first time click on textField. If I click it second time then the date picker view is opened. I'm confused in this case. Why it did not open at first click? How to show date picker view in first click on `UITextField`?

**Code I have try:**

```
@IBAction func datePick(sender: UITextField)
{
    let datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    sender.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SendSMS.showDatePicker), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func showDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:SS"
    timeField.text = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    dateField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: did you get action in the first click at func datePick?? I hope you are not getting the action, because on the first click your simulator is selected ; then only you are clicking date text fileld..watch carefully :D

Comment: cool.. happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting action with `textField` try to use delegate method of `UITextFieldDelegate`.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {    //delegate method
    if textField == dateField {
        let datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        textField.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SendSMS.showDatePicker), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It'll also work by setting TextField action event `Editing Did Begin`. It won't work first time if you set the action `Editing Did End`.